# Как удалить объект массива по id объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
items: [
            {
                id: 9,
                label: 'List item 1'
            },
            {
                id: 13,
                label: 'List item 2'
            },
            {
                id: 24,
                label: 'List item 3'
            },
            {
                id: 35,
                label: 'List item 4'
            },
            {
                id: 123,
                label: 'List item 5'
            }
        ]
```

Как удалить элемент массива не по индексу [0, 1, 2, 3, ...4], а по id объектов?

Answer (score -1):

```
items.forEach((value, key) => {
    if(value.id == 24)
        delete items[key]
})
```

Таким образом будет удален объект у которого `id` равен 24.

Comment: `forEach` для модификации масива и `delete`. double kill

Comment: @ddeadlink `forEach` Ясно, не к месту, а вот `delete`, чем плох?

Comment: для данного примера приемлемо, а вообще если существует цепочка прототипов этого не стоит делать, + делит удаляет не обьект а ссылку на него, соответственно в памяти он останется

Comment: @ddeadlink ну тут цепочки прототипов не наблюдается, а удаления последний ссылки на объект, подводит его в сборщику мусора, после чего он будет бесследно очищен. Если бы мы сделали тоже самое с помощью `slice` Например, мы бы просто удалили последую ссылку.